# Inserir para chaves estrangeiras SQL

Tags: c#, sql, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

estou aprendendo uma linguagem de programação e me propus a desenvolver um programa de orçamentos. O meu primeiro obstáculo está sendo adicionar os valores das chaves primárias nas chaves estrangeiras das tabelas respectivas. Este código abaixo funciona bem para isto, mas após copiar a PK da tabela Cliente para FK da tabela Orcamento, os próximos dados sempre adicionam-se às linhas seguintes da tabela e não à linha atual como deve ser. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Segue um trecho do meu código:

```
connect.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd1= new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Cliente(nome, endereco)"+"Values (@nome, @endereco)", connect); // nome e endereço
        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Produto(nome, preco)" + "Values (@nomeProd, @precoProd)", connect); //produto, preço
        OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Orcamento(id_cliente) SELECT MAX(id) FROM Cliente", connect);
        //Como eu faria para adicionar a informação "data" que está numa string no objeto acima, como as demais (cmd1 e cmd2) tendo em vista que existe o comando SELECT?

        if(connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nome",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = nome;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@endereco",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = endereco;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = nomeProd;
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@preco", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = precoProd;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@id_cliente", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = "";
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@data", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = data;
            try 
            {           
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja a possibilidade de criar uma proc, pelo que vejo é inserido dados nas 3 tabelas de uma unica vez, assim vc poderia fazer da seguinte forma...

Criar a proc com os parâmetros necessarios

```
create Proc  Cliente_Orcamento  
(
  @nome nvarchar(50),
  @endereco nvarchar(50),
  @nomeProd  nvarchar(50),
  @precoProd numeric(18,2), 
  @data datetime,
  @IdCliente_Out int output
)
as
begin

  Set Xact_Abort on
  Set Nocount on
  Begin Tran

  begin
    INSERT into Cliente(nome, endereco) Values (@nome, @endereco)
    Set @IdCliente_Out = @@IDENTITY -- aqui vc pegar o id do cliente do
    -- ultimo insert.. linha executada acima    

    INSERT into Produto(nome, preco) Values (@nomeProd, @precoProd)
    INSERT into Orcamento(id_cliente) Values (@IdCliente_Out)
  end
  Commit
end
```

Chama assim

```
connect.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd1= new OleDbCommand("Cliente_Orcamento", connect); 

    if(connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nome",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = nome;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@endereco",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = endereco;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nomeProd", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = nomeProd;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@precoProd", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = precoProd;
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@data", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = data;
        try 
        {           
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada nesse proc. Ainda não sei como funciona. O código da textbox superior vai na minha classe como um procedimento? Obrigado pela ajuda tão rápida.

Comment: Não descobri como fazer este procedimento (Strored Procedures) no banco de dados criado pelo Access. Posso utilizar apenas o comando update para atualizar as chaves estrangeiras?

Comment: @Vanderlei, ah sim no MSAccess não tem suporte para  `Strored Procedures `, achava que era sql server. uma alternativa para isso seria vc após executar seu  `cmd1` fazer o select `SELECT MAX(id) FROM Cliente ` e amazenar o valor de retorno para passa no   `cmd3.Parameters`.

Comment: O problema é que o cmd3 já faz isto, só que quando eu crio um objeto cmd4 que irá trabalhar na mesma linha do cmd3, o INSERT faz a informação @data ir para a linha seguinte. Ainda não consegui descobrir porque isto ocorre. Vou tentar usar o cmd3 para passar a data e no cmd4 tentar usar UPDATE FROM SELECT. Obrigado pelo suporte.